# how to place text and images in small sized page using iText

Tags: java, itext

I need to make a PDF page that looks something like this:

[image: Desired output]

I'm having problems to make two columns that fit on a small sized page.

This is my code:

```
public void createSizedPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));        
        document.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        Rectangle one = new Rectangle(290,100);
        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);        
        document.setPageSize(one);
        document.open();

        Paragraph consigneeName = new Paragraph("Ahmed");
        Paragraph address = new Paragraph("Casa ST 121");
        String codeBL = "14785236987541"; 

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
        code128.setBaseline(9);
        code128.setSize(9);
        code128.setCode(codeBL);
        code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
        Image code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
        Paragraph right = new Paragraph();
        right.add(consigneeName);
        right.add(address);
        right.add(code128Image);

        Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(right);
        p.add(new Chunk(glue));
        p.add(code128Image);

       document.add(p); 
       document.close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using iText 5 or iText 7? What have you tried? You are asking something *extremely trivial*, so it is hard for us to understand your problem: are you unable to scale images? are you unable to define a smaller font size? are you unable to create a table with specific dimension? You say *I'm having problems to make two columns that fits in a small sized page* but you forgot to describe the problems. Please improve your question.

Comment: i've just edited the question with some code snippet as for the iText version i'm using iText5, plus a link to what i'm trying to do

Comment: IS there a specific reason why you don't want to use an AcroForm template to do this kind of work? Wouldn't that be more elegant and flexible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your problem, would be to create a template PDF with AcroForm fields. You could create a nice design manually, and then fill out the form programmatically by putting data (text, bar codes) at the appropriate places defined by the fields that act as placeholders.

Another way, is to create the PDF from scratch, which is the approach you seem to have taken, looking at your code.

Your question isn't entirely clear, in the sense that you share your code, but you don't explain the problem you are experiencing. As I already commented:

> are you unable to scale images? are you unable to define a smaller
>   font size? are you unable to create a table with specific dimension?
>   You say I'm having problems to make two columns that fits in a small
>   sized page but you forgot to describe the problems.

You didn't give an answer to those questions, and that makes it very hard for someone to answer your question. The only thing a Stack Overflow reader could do, is to do your work in your place. That's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Moreover, the answer to your question is so trivial that it is hard for a Stack Overflow reader to understand why you posted a question.

You say you need to add data (text and bar codes) in two columns, you are actually saying that you want to create a table. This is an example of such a table:

[image]

If you look at the [SmallTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/101-very-simple-table#2830-smalltable.java) example, you can see how it's built.

You want a PDF that measures 290 by 100 user units, with a margin of 5 user units on each side. This means that you have space for a table measuring 280 by 90 user units. Looking at your screen shot, I'd say that you have a column of 160 user units with and a column of 120 user units. I'd also say that you have three rows of 30 user units high each.

OK, then why don't you create a table based on those dimensions?

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Rectangle small = new Rectangle(290,100);
    Font smallfont = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10);
    Document document = new Document(small, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{ 160, 120 });
    table.setLockedWidth(true);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    // first row
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some text here"));
    cell.setFixedHeight(30);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // second row
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some more text", smallfont));
    cell.setFixedHeight(30);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell(cell);
    Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
    code128.setCode("14785236987541");
    code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
    Image code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
    cell = new PdfPCell(code128Image, true);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setFixedHeight(30);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // third row
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("and something else here", smallfont));
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

In this example,

- you learn how to change the font of the content in a cell,
- you learn how to change horizontal and vertical alignment,
- you learn how to scale a bar code so that it fits into a cell,
- ...

All of this functionality is explained in the official documentation. As I said before: you didn't explain the nature of your problem. What wasn't clear in the documentation for you? What is your question?

Comment: thanks for your clair and detailed answer, and i'm sorry for the ambiguity of my question, what i was trying to do is to figure out how to position elements like paragraphs, images barcodes in an absolute position in a pdf page, something like in java swing when you set a JPanel layer to null and place buttons and labels by setting their bounds, your answer helped alot thanks again.